# Fixed points of unit disk automorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Given mobvius transformations of the form $$f(z) = \eta\frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}$$ with $\vert \eta \vert = 1$ and $a\in\mathbb{D}$ ($\mathbb{D}= $ open unit disk).
I have to proof that if this transformation have two fixed points $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{D}$, $f(z)$ is already the identity $f(z)=z$.

We can consider $\eta\not=-1$ (that case is kinda trivial, no fixed points IN $\mathbb{D}$, but on the boarder). I calculated the fixed points for some examples and found a pattern: If one fixed point is $z$, the other one is $\frac{1}{\bar z}$. That would already proofs the claim. Because if $z$ is inside $\mathbb{D}$, than $\frac{1}{\bar z}$ is not. And since $f(z)$ has at most two fixed points we are done.

But I struggle very hard to proof that if one fixed point is $z$, $\frac{1}{z}$ is the other. I start with $$\eta\frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}=z$$ and expand $\frac{z}{1}$ to $\frac{\vert z \vert^2}{\bar z}$ and then I do some algebra. I tried many different approaches to prove this, but since I am unable to do so I think that this is not true in general case..
Can anyone help me out? I dont necessarily need an entire solution, but some hints would be nice. Am I on the right path? Or is everything I did so far kinda useless?

Comment: suppose first of all $0$ is fixed and that $p\neq 0$ is another fixed point. [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) gives you the result immediately. How does the general case follow from this?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any theorems like Schwarz's lemma available :/

Comment: If $a=0$ then trivially having two fixed points implies it is the identity. Otherwise, by expanding out the equation $f(z)=z$, I found $\bar{a}z^2-(\eta+1)z+\eta a=0$; if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the roots of this quadratic (i.e these are the fixed points) then $\bar{a}z_1z_2=\eta a$, and hence $|z_1z_2|=1$. Therefore, it is NOT possible to have both these fixed points lying inside the unit disc.